# Is there a way to optimize getting the odd number?

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a way to optimize this code, it is a fairly simple question but I think a 30 line code is too much.

"Write a program that examines three variables: x,y,z and prints the largest odd number among them. If none of them are odd, it should print a message to that effect."

```
if x%2 != 0 and y%2 != 0 and z%2 != 0:
  if x > y and x > z:
    print(x)
  elif y > x and y > z:
    print(y)
  else:
    print(z)
elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 != 0 and z%2 != 0:
  if y > z:
    print(y)
  else:
    print(z)
elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 != 0:
  if x > z:
    print(x)
  else:
    print(z)
elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 != 0 and z%2 == 0:
  if x > y:
    print(x)
  else:
    print(y)       
elif x%2 != 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 0:
  print(x)
elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 != 0 and z%2 == 0:
  print(y)
elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 != 0:
  print(z) 
else:
  print('None of them are odd')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manipulate more numbers is to use some data structure like `list`. One of the solution is:

```py
numbers = [x, y, z]
odds = list(filter (lambda x: x%2 !=0, numbers))

if odds: 
  print (max(odds))
else:
  print('There is no odd')
```

Comment: Max will only be evaluated if list is not empty.

Comment: You don't need `!=0`, just `x%2` will suffice.

Comment: I think It can increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
odd_nums = [n for n in [x, y, z] if n%2]

if odd_nums:
    print(max(odd_nums))
else:
    print('None of them are odd')
```

### How it works

1. For choosing the maximum, you can use the built-in function max(), which [requires an iterable as argument](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max). So, we'll put  `x`, `y`, and `z` in a list.
2. But we want only the `x`, `y`, and `z` that are odd, i.e. such that `n%2 != 0`. So, we would like to do something like

```
odd_nums = []
for n in [x, y, z]:
    if n%2 != 0:
        odd_nums.append(n)
```

But we can write this shorter and nicer using [*list comprehension*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/):

```
odd_nums = [n for n in [x, y, z] if n%2 != 0]
```

But, as pointed by @BeRT2me, since n%2 will evaluate to `True` if it's not `0`, we can eliminate the unnecessary comparison. Your CPU is a calculator: good for maths but bad for logic so it's better to avoid conditionals and comparisons when possible.

3. If there were no odd numbers in `[x, y, z]`, then the result is going to be an empty list (`[]`, which would evaluate to `False` is converted to bool). So we can choose what to print by doing

```
if odd_nums:  # True if odd_nums is not empty
    print(max(odd_nums))
else:  # if odd_nums = []
    print('None of them are odd')
```

### Bonus

If you expect that more frequently at least one number is going to be odd and cases with only even numbers are unusual, you could make your code slightly more efficient by replacing the `if`/`else` statement by a `try`/`except`:

```
odd_nums = [n for n in [x, y, z] if n%2]

try:
    print(max(odd_nums))
except ValueError:
    print('None of them are odd')
```

Comment: You don't need `!= 0`, just `n%2` will suffice.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

1. Put the numbers in a set.
2. Keep odd numbers in the set.
3. Find the greatest odd number in odd numbers (using max()).

```
numbers = {x, y, z}
odd_numbers = [ number for number in numbers if number % 2 == 1 ]
greatest_odd_number = max(odd_numbers)
```

Or, in just one line,
`max([ number for number in {x, y, z} if number % 2 == 1 ])`

Comment: You don't need `== 1`, just `number % 2`. will suffice.

Comment: True, `== 1` is not necessary to get the correct output. However, this is a matter of style preference. When using conditions, some programmers prefer to explicitly show a comparison that evaluates to a `bool` type even if that's not something the language enforces or requires.